# Algolia place how to return country in iso?

Tags: algolia

hello i works with algolia place
i load country via

```
document.querySelector(\'#'.$elementid_n.'_country\').value = e.suggestion.country || \'\';
```

but it return complet name of country ..
how to return FR for french and other countrie
regards

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `suggestion.countryCode` instead of `suggestion.country`

Here's also a reference to the algolia-documentation about [suggestion.countryCode](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#api-suggestion-countryCode)